# How can i set vertical text on q-table header quasar?

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, quasar-framework, quasar, vuetify-datatable

I'm trying to parse some excel sheets for my web project and in this q-table I need to set two columns with vertical text just like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLLND.png) but when I try to rotate it changes all columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, assign unique names for header cells. For example:

```
  {
    name: 'first',
    align: 'center',
    label: 'First col header',
    field: row => row.value
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    align: 'center',
    label: 'Second col header',
    field: row => row.value
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    align: 'center',
    label: 'Third col header',
    field: row => row.value
  },
  {
    name: 'fourth',
    align: 'center',
    label: 'Fourth col header',
    field: row => row.value
  },
]
```

- Then. leverage the [header-cell-[name] slot](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#example--header-cell-name-slot) to target the headers by their names, and add CSS class `.text-vertical` to headers that need to be vertical.
  Like this:

```
 <q-table
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="name"
    >
      <template v-slot:header-cell-second="props">
        <q-th :props="props">
          <span class="text-vertical">
            {{ props.col.label }}
          </span>
        </q-th>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:header-cell-third="props">
        <q-th :props="props">
          <span class="text-vertical">
            {{ props.col.label }}
          </span>
        </q-th>
      </template>
</q-table>
```

- CSS:

```
.text-vertical{
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg)
}
```

- You could give a look to my implementation in codepen:
  https://codepen.io/hoangdng-the-sans/pen/xxjNxgv